# How do you click on a container and trigger the page to scroll to a specific area of the webpage?

Tags: html

Here is the container:

```
.divider {display:block; position: absolute; top:calc(100vh - 80px); width: 100%; text-align: center; font-family: "Avenir Lt Std", Arial; color:white; font-size:12px; background-color:#005A85;padding-top:8px; padding-bottom: 30px; z-index:-1}
```

Here is the container in the html:

```
<section class="divider">
<h2> text text</h2>
</section>
```

The expected behavior would be that when users click on "text text", the page scroll to the bottom of the website or a specific area of the page.

Comment: How are you wanting to do this?  Html, javascript, jquery?
we need more information as several approaches available

Comment: What ever way is the easiest to allow for the same behavior across website, mobile app, ipad.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific div or something you want it to jump to just use:

```
<a href="#divIdOrSomething"><h2>text text</h2>
```

If you want to use javascript and don't have a specific anchor tag to jump to use

```
window.scrollTo(0, 500);
```

it will jump "500" horizontal change the value prentending where you want to jump to.

javascript with motion

```
$('html, body').animate({
     window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
},500); // scroll animation time in milliseconds
```

Comment: Does using the java script give the scrolling motion? If yes, 1) how do you implement in html? (sorry I'm new to this?)  2) how do you simply scroll to the bottom of the page?  Thanks!

Comment: added to my answer the havascript to give an scrolling animation. Then just add an onclick in html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to have an anchor tag Text then place the actual tag where you want it to fall in the content of the webpage. as such: 
    `<a href="#anchor">Click me</a>
    some text for the webpage.
    more text
    extra stuff
    <a id="anchor">`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to replicate a scroll motion instead of just jump to the anchor?

Answer (score 0):

See this Jquery example

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/fvp0jjn3/)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".divider").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: how do you change the button to a link?

Comment: use href and provide listener on it  or directly give id in href but i think the above solution is help you